# Play specific song

Tags: ios, mpmediaplayercontroller

I am looking at ways to store song information and then play a specific song.  I've seen this post:
[How do you use MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID to play music in iPhone Music Player Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570858/how-do-you-use-mpmediaitempropertypersistentid-to-play-music-in-iphone-music-pla)

If I have a `MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID` already, can I directly play that song without looping every single song until I find a matching id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do this by looping through all the items in the library. It can be done via MPMediaQuery, something like this:

```
NSNumber *persistentIDNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:4238475234];

MPMusicPlayerController *player = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];

MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:persistentIDNumber forProperty:MPMediaEntityPropertyPersistentID];

MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];

[query addFilterPredicate: predicate];

[player setQueueWithQuery:query];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
```